# htaccess to non www with SSL and file extension rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

I have a website that rewrites the .php file extension so: 
http://example.com/about.php 
becomes 
http://example.com/about

I also redirect www.domain.com to non www.

Now I am going to move it over to SSL, so I want to keep those 2 rules and redirect it all to https as well.

Here is what I currently have:

```
# Redirect to non www version
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^index.php / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

How can I do this without too many redirects? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the URLs that cause too many redirects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE] 

RewriteRule ^index.php / [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

Comment: Thanks @wp78de , I have yet to try it but I was wondering why you used a 302 redirect in the first part?

Comment: @Sara44 301 should be fine too.

Comment: Many thanks that worked. Apologies for the time in accepting the answer.